# HTML table data is too wide

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I create a simple table in HTML, however the "Address" cell in the table is very very wide but all I'm doing is giving it a title and entering a number.

[image: See the address column - it is far too wide]

The code the Address column is very simple:

```
<TH>Address</TH><TH>Literal  etc
```

Then the data is added with:

```
<TD valign=baseline>0x110</TD>
```

yet the address column is enormous. I have no style sheets set up.
I just want a small "Address" cell !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you didn't provide all the code. From your screen shot, it looks as this `CLOCK_OUTPUTS_PARAMS_SUBBLOCK_PPS PARAMETERS` is causing this. You probably need to add a `colspan` to that cell.

Answer (score 0):

After re-looking at the photo you posted. That title is way close to that gap to be a coincidence. I think one bug you may have is putting the Clock into a table header and did not break a table row before showing the other headers. Did you use Clock_.....Address ? Because if so this can fix your problem:

```
<tr><th colspan=7 align='left'>Clock_...</th></tr>
<tr><th>Address</th><th>Literal</td> //etc
```

To re-size the cells just add a width property (make sure to add this to every cell in the left most column).

```
<TD width=20 valign=baseline>0x110</TD>
```

If that doesn't work you can use CSS to style them. You can do this by adding this style in the  of your web-page. Then add class='left_col' into each of your left most column cells.

```
<style>
.left_col {
max-width:20px;
}
<style>

<TD class='left_col' valign=baseline>0x110</TD>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `CLOCK_OUTPUTS_PARAMS_SUBBLOCK_PPS PARAMETERS` is the title of the table, you should put it in a `<caption>` element rather than a table cell.

```
<table>
    <caption>CLOCK_OUTPUTS_PARAMS_SUBBLOCK_PPS PARAMETERS</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr> (rest of table...)
```